# regexp to only extract first set/group of numbers from line of string from a file

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, ansible, yaml

How can I use regexp to extract first set/group of numbers from line of string from a file and **ignore lines** that have two set of numbers, any symbol (except PASS_MAX_DAYS), and have it show on the terminal. I am not doing any modifying on the file(login.defs).

Example(only bold numbers)

PASS_MAX_DAYS **30**

PASS_MAX_DAYS  30 .12  (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS $30  (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS 30  23  (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 days  (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_@DAYS 30  (Ignore)

```
- name: extract num from pass max days
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/login.defs
        state: absent
        regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
      check_mode: yes
      register: days

    - name: show password max days
      debug:
        msg: "{{days}}" #Show max days
      when: days <= 90
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the file

```
shell> cat /tmp/login.defs 
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 .12
PASS_MAX_DAYS $30
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 23
PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 days
PASS_MAX_@DAYS 30
```

Read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/login.defs
      register: out
```

Put the declarations below, for example, into the playbook vars

```yaml
regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
pass_max_days: "{{ out.stdout_lines|
                   select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
pass_max_days: '30'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
    pass_max_days: "{{ out.stdout_lines|
                       select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/login.defs
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: pass_max_days
```

---

Q: ***"How can I use the days for comparison?"***

A: Convert it to an integer. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Less than 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int < 90
    - debug:
        msg: Exactly 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int == 90
    - debug:
        msg: More than 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int > 90
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Less than 90 days

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: How can I use the days for comparison? Example, - debug:
        var: pass_max_days when: days < 90

Comment: @JakePaul If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.