# Match only first number from exact 'word' and ignore if fail

Tags: ansible, yaml

Currently I have written this to extract numbers from PASS_MAX_DAYS **[number]**. I want it to ignore if it matches the example.

Example(only bold numbers)

PASS_MAX_DAYS **30**

pass_max_days **30**

PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 .12 (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS $30 (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 23 (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_DAYS 30 days (Ignore)

PASS_MAX_@DAYS 30 (Ignore)

```
- hosts: web
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:    
    - slurp:
        path: /etc/login.defs
      register: max_days

    - name: comparing number and outputing result
      vars:
        days: '{{ max_days.content | b64decode | regex_replace("(?si)^.*PASS_MAX_DAYS\D*(\d+).*$", "\1", multiline=True) }}'
      debug:
        msg: "[ PASSED ] - Ensure password expiration is 90 days or less"
      when: days | int <= 90
```

Comment: Could you describe the difference between this question and your previous one? [regexp to only extract first set/group of numbers from line of string from a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715562)

Comment: Does the solution under [Display message when regex does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567101/6771046) helps here?